# C arithmetic expression inconsistency with printf and assignment to another variable

Tags: c, expression, precision, numeric

Below program outputs different values for a/100 where a is int.

```
void main()
{
    int a = -150;
    float f;
    f = a/100;
    printf(" %f,%f ",f,a/100);
}
```

Output: -1.000000,0.000000

Here second %f value comes up to 0.000000, but how is it possible, it should be -1.000000 or -1.500000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no inconsistency:

```
 f = a/100;
```

performs integer division stored into a float: result `1.0`

then

```
 printf(" %f ",a/100);
```

prints an integer (1), but with float format: undefined behaviour.

this works without surprises:

```
void main()
{
    int a = -150;
    float f;
    f = a/100.0;
    printf(" %f,%f ",f,a/100.0);
}
```

`printf` is a variable arguments function (prototype: `void printf(const char *,...)`), which has no other choice than to "believe" the format that you pass.

If you tell `printf` that second argument is a float, then it will read the argument bytestream as a `float`, and if the data doesn't match a `float` structure, well, it won't work properly.

EDIT: compiler makers know that this is a common mistake, so they have added a special check for the printf-like functions: if you compile your file with gcc using `-Wall` or `-Wformat` options you'll get the following explicit message:

```
foo.c:8:1: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
 printf(" %f,%f ",f,150/100);
```

(same goes if the number of `%`-like format arguments and the number of arguments do not match).

Comment: So, I should not use %f with an underlying integer unless I cast? ( Say, I do not want to use 100.0 as denominator). I knew it would print correctly when the modifications you had mentioned are done. MY POINT IS WHY DOES IT NOT INHERENTLY typecast int to float when %f format specifier is used.

Comment: @iharob: what was I thinking :) edited. no need for further complexity...